# If the element has an empty value in the array. Then tell all the next items false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hellow All. I heve some issue. I want to find in an array the first element with an empty value and set all other elements to fals. I've tried many different options. But so far, only the variant with the current element works.

```
 someArray.map(e: any, inex: any, a: any) => {

  if (e.instruction.length > 0) {
    return e.isEmpty = false
  }

  return ( someHtml)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
const isNotEmptyFirstItem = someArray[0].instruction.length > 0;
const updatedArray = isNotEmptyFirstItem && someArray.map(item => item.isEmpty = false);
}
```

And you can do what you want with the updatedArray.

Comment: Almoust, but it halpe2. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
const FuncToCheck = (el) => el === true
cosnt faindElemIndex = someArray.faindIndex((el) => FuncToCheck(el))
const setCheck = () => {
  if (indexOfMap > faindElemIndex) { return false } 
    else return true
}
```